# Equal number of element per row with flexbox?

Tags: css

I have dynamic content and a responsive layout, so the number of items and available width will vary. Sometimes elements in a div will need to wrap onto a second 'row'.

With flexbox (or any other CSS method) can you make the number of items on each row be equal?

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>

.cont {
  display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.elem {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;

  display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEQzqY

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you suggested using media queries for different screen sizes?

Comment: My content is dynamic. I dont know how many elements there are so I dont think media queries will work.

Comment: Given that 7 is a prime number, how would you determine how exactly to distribute flex items? Think about it.

Comment: If there is an odd number could there be an intelligent interpretation? See the image in my question.

Comment: i think [css columns](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/) will help

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Ive read that article and I dont think it will do what I need.

Comment: @Evans Did you ever find a solution? I don't have dynamic content, I have 6 elements but on full screen it wraps 4-2 when I want it to be 3-3.

Comment: I know i'm late to the party but if the ordering of the elements does not matter then you can possibly do a column flows instead of rows.

Answer (score 4):

If the number of elements are within reason, it may be feasible writing css for each individual case using the [quantity queries](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) technique.

Comment: I dont think thats a possibility for me. Ive updated my question with a new image.

Comment: What a great resource!

Answer (score 3):

I'm over 2 years late, buuut I liked Maksym Stepanenko's idea.
I originally tried a pure css solution with flexbox using:

```
flex-direction: column;
align-content: flex-start;
```

but this would require you to specify a Height, and adjust the Height as needed.

So the Back-up approach using Maksym Stepanenko's idea of adjusting margin-right as needed, works with floating elements or flexbox wrapped elements, either way.
I ended up correcting some of Maksym Stepanenko's calculations for this example:

[JS BIN Link](http://jsbin.com/secisuxayu/1/edit?html,output) or code snippet below (using a library 'Detect Element Resize' so the container listener works).

```js
/**
* Detect Element Resize
*
* https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize
* Sebastian Decima
*
* version: 0.5.3
**/

(function () {
 var attachEvent = document.attachEvent,
  stylesCreated = false;
 
 if (!attachEvent) {
  var requestFrame = (function(){
   var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(fn){ return window.setTimeout(fn, 20); };
   return function(fn){ return raf(fn); };
  })();
  
  var cancelFrame = (function(){
   var cancel = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame || window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame ||
           window.clearTimeout;
    return function(id){ return cancel(id); };
  })();

  function resetTriggers(element){
   var triggers = element.__resizeTriggers__,
    expand = triggers.firstElementChild,
    contract = triggers.lastElementChild,
    expandChild = expand.firstElementChild;
   contract.scrollLeft = contract.scrollWidth;
   contract.scrollTop = contract.scrollHeight;
   expandChild.style.width = expand.offsetWidth + 1 + 'px';
   expandChild.style.height = expand.offsetHeight + 1 + 'px';
   expand.scrollLeft = expand.scrollWidth;
   expand.scrollTop = expand.scrollHeight;
  };

  function checkTriggers(element){
   return element.offsetWidth != element.__resizeLast__.width ||
       element.offsetHeight != element.__resizeLast__.height;
  }
  
  function scrollListener(e){
   var element = this;
   resetTriggers(this);
   if (this.__resizeRAF__) cancelFrame(this.__resizeRAF__);
   this.__resizeRAF__ = requestFrame(function(){
    if (checkTriggers(element)) {
     element.__resizeLast__.width = element.offsetWidth;
     element.__resizeLast__.height = element.offsetHeight;
     element.__resizeListeners__.forEach(function(fn){
      fn.call(element, e);
     });
    }
   });
  };
  
  /* Detect CSS Animations support to detect element display/re-attach */
  var animation = false,
   animationstring = 'animation',
   keyframeprefix = '',
   animationstartevent = 'animationstart',
   domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms'.split(' '),
   startEvents = 'webkitAnimationStart animationstart oAnimationStart MSAnimationStart'.split(' '),
   pfx  = '';
  {
   var elm = document.createElement('fakeelement');
   if( elm.style.animationName !== undefined ) { animation = true; }    
   
   if( animation === false ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < domPrefixes.length; i++ ) {
     if( elm.style[ domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName' ] !== undefined ) {
      pfx = domPrefixes[ i ];
      animationstring = pfx + 'Animation';
      keyframeprefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
      animationstartevent = startEvents[ i ];
      animation = true;
      break;
     }
    }
   }
  }
  
  var animationName = 'resizeanim';
  var animationKeyframes = '@' + keyframeprefix + 'keyframes ' + animationName + ' { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 0; } } ';
  var animationStyle = keyframeprefix + 'animation: 1ms ' + animationName + '; ';
 }
 
 function createStyles() {
  if (!stylesCreated) {
   //opacity:0 works around a chrome bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=286360
   var css = (animationKeyframes ? animationKeyframes : '') +
     '.resize-triggers { ' + (animationStyle ? animationStyle : '') + 'visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; } ' +
     '.resize-triggers, .resize-triggers > div, .contract-trigger:before { content: \" \"; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; } .resize-triggers > div { background: #eee; overflow: auto; } .contract-trigger:before { width: 200%; height: 200%; }',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');
   
   style.type = 'text/css';
   if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
   } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
   }

   head.appendChild(style);
   stylesCreated = true;
  }
 }
 
 window.addResizeListener = function(element, fn){
  if (attachEvent) element.attachEvent('onresize', fn);
  else {
   if (!element.__resizeTriggers__) {
    if (getComputedStyle(element).position == 'static') element.style.position = 'relative';
    createStyles();
    element.__resizeLast__ = {};
    element.__resizeListeners__ = [];
    (element.__resizeTriggers__ = document.createElement('div')).className = 'resize-triggers';
    element.__resizeTriggers__.innerHTML = '<div class="expand-trigger"><div></div></div>' +
                      '<div class="contract-trigger"></div>';
    element.appendChild(element.__resizeTriggers__);
    resetTriggers(element);
    element.addEventListener('scroll', scrollListener, true);
    
    /* Listen for a css animation to detect element display/re-attach */
    animationstartevent && element.__resizeTriggers__.addEventListener(animationstartevent, function(e) {
     if(e.animationName == animationName)
      resetTriggers(element);
    });
   }
   element.__resizeListeners__.push(fn);
  }
 };
 
 window.removeResizeListener = function(element, fn){
  if (attachEvent) element.detachEvent('onresize', fn);
  else {
   element.__resizeListeners__.splice(element.__resizeListeners__.indexOf(fn), 1);
   if (!element.__resizeListeners__.length) {
     element.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);
     element.__resizeTriggers__ = !element.removeChild(element.__resizeTriggers__);
   }
  }
 }
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.flex{ display: -webkit-flex; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; }
.wrap{ -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; flex-wrap: wrap;}
.cont {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  width: 448px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  /*flex-direction: column;height: 225px;align-content: flex-start;*/
}
.controls{
  width: 500px; 
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}
.elem {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align:center;
}
input{
 width: 25px; color: blue;
}
#resizableBorder{
 resize: horizontal;
 overflow: auto;
}
</style>
<style id="jsManipulated">
.elem {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 line-height: 100px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cont {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<br> 
<div class="flex controls">
  <button id="adder">(+) add item</button>
  <button id="remover">(-) remove item</button>
  <span> Box Size: 
    <input id="sizer" type="text" value="100" boxCountlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode > 47 && event.charCode < 58'>
  </span>
  <span> Padding: 
    <input id="padder" type="text" value="10" boxCountlength="3" >
</div>
<br><hr><br>
<div id="resizableBorder" class="cont flex wrap">
  <div class="elem"> 1</div><div class="elem"> 2</div><div class="elem"> 3</div>
  <div class="elem"> 4</div><div class="elem"> 5</div><div class="elem"> 6</div>
  <div class="elem"> 7</div><div class="elem"> 8</div><div class="elem"> 9</div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  
  var boxCount = 9;
  var boxWidth = 100;
  var boxBorderWidth = 10;
  var adder = document.getElementById('adder');
  var remover = document.getElementById('remover');
  var sizer = document.getElementById('sizer');
  var padder = document.getElementById('padder');
  var flexParent = document.getElementsByClassName('cont')[0];
  var styleEle = document.getElementById('jsManipulated');
  var resizableBorder = document.getElementById('resizableBorder');
  
  function addItem(){
    console.log("add");
    var newItem = document.createElement('div');
    newItem.className += 'elem';
    newItem.innerHTML = ++boxCount;
    flexParent.appendChild( newItem );
    repaint();
  }

  function removeItem(){
    console.log("remove");
    if(boxCount != 0){
     --boxCount;
     //flexParent.removeChild(flexParent.lastChild);
 var position = flexParent.children.length -1;
 if( flexParent.children[position].className == "resize-triggers"){ --position; } //ignore resize-triggers div.
     flexParent.removeChild( flexParent.children[ position ] );
     repaint();
    }
  }

  function resizeBoxes(event) {
 if( event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58){ boxWidth = this.value; } 
 else if( event.keyCode == 40 ){ boxWidth = --this.value;  }
 else if( event.keyCode == 38 ){ boxWidth = ++this.value; }
 else { 
  console.log('non-numeric keypress ignored: '+event.keyCode); 
  return;
        }
 updateBoxStyles( boxWidth, boxBorderWidth);
  }

  function repadBoxes(event) {
 if( event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58){ boxBorderWidth= this.value; } 
 else if( event.keyCode == 40 ){ boxBorderWidth = --this.value; }
 else if( event.keyCode == 38 ){ boxBorderWidth = ++this.value;}
 else { 
  console.log('non-numeric keypress ignored: '+event.keyCode); 
  return;
        }
 updateBoxStyles( boxWidth, boxBorderWidth);
  }

  function updateBoxStyles( size, edge ){
 styleEle.innerHTML = 
 ".elem { height: "
 +size+"px; width: "
 +size+"px; line-height: "
 +size+"px; margin-right: "
 +edge+"px; margin-bottom: "
 +edge+"px;} .cont { padding-top: "
 +edge+"px; padding-left: "
 +edge+"px;}"
 repaint();
  }

  /* LISTENERS */
  window.onresize = repaint; //Only needed if 'width' of container is a percentage ex: '.cont{width:60%}'
  adder.addEventListener('click', addItem );
  remover.addEventListener('click', removeItem );
  sizer.addEventListener('keyup', resizeBoxes );
  padder.addEventListener('keyup', repadBoxes );
  addResizeListener( resizableBorder, repaint); //using the 'detect-element-resize.js library'

  
  /** Most Important Function Called Everytime Anything Changes, in order to keep elements to the left using 'margin-right' **/
  repaint(); //initial resize on pageload;
  function repaint() {
      console.log('repaint');
      var elementWidth = 2- -boxWidth- -boxBorderWidth; // 2 because: border is 1px*2, '- -' because '+' causes string concatination.
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('elem');
      var count = elements.length;
      var parentWidth = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( flexParent).getPropertyValue('width') );
      var rowsCount = Math.ceil( count / Math.floor(parentWidth/elementWidth) );
      var perRow = Math.floor( count / rowsCount);
      var extra = count % rowsCount;

      for (var i=0, ele; ele = elements[i]; i++) {
   ele.style["margin-right"] = "";
      }

      if( rowsCount == Infinity || rowsCount == 0){ return; }//when elementWidth < parentWidth or Zero Boxes

      var allPrevRowsTotal = 0;
      for (var i = 1; i <= rowsCount && rowsCount > 1; i++) {
   var perThisRow = perRow;
   if( extra != 0){ --extra; perThisRow++; }
   elements[ allPrevRowsTotal + perThisRow - 1 ].style["margin-right"] = parentWidth - (perThisRow * elementWidth) +"px";
   allPrevRowsTotal += perThisRow;
      }
  }

});

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125444/equal-number-of-element-per-row-with-flexbox
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As dalgard says, quantity queries is a solution if you want a CSS solution.

However, you will need to write several cases

Lets see it working for the seven elements case

```css
.cont {
  display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.elem {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;

  display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.elem:nth-last-child(7):first-child {
  border-color: red;
  }
.elem:nth-last-child(7):first-child ~ .elem:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: green;
  margin-right: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

I have set the red border rule just to show that it applies to the seven elements case, but niot to others case. Then, the third element afert this is targeted to make the row finish (and display with a different border color to make this visible

Comment: Does this mean I would need to have different CSS based on how many elements there are? As my content is dynamic this isnt possible for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although you asked for Css solution I couldn't find one , so I created a jquery based solution ( As I assume can be optimized alot).

This solution works only if you know the item width and it is static as in your example (currently `112px` with `border` and `margin`).

Hope this suites your needs.

Css And HTML are unchanged

### Javascript

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var elementWidth = 112;
    var Elements = $(".elem");
    var parentWidth = $(".cont").width();
    var rowsCount = Math.ceil((Elements.length * elementWidth) / parentWidth);
    var perRow = Math.ceil(Elements.length / rowsCount);
    perRow = perRow * elementWidth > parentWidth ? perRow - 1 : perRow;
    $.each(Elements, function (index, item) {
        $(this).css("margin-right", "");
    });

    for (i = 1; i <= rowsCount && rowsCount > 1; i++) {
        if (i * perRow <= Elements.length) Elements.eq((i * perRow) - 1).css("margin-right", parentWidth - (perRow * elementWidth));
    }
});
```

### Here Is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y16fke1/4/)

## NOTE

This hasn't been tested on all screen sizes and different numbers of elements,
just a couple of cases, so i may fail at some point.