# How to evenly distribute elements in a div in a dynamic fashion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

How do I style a div so that equal size elements are always evenly spaced from each other horizontally and vertically regardless of window size?

For example: Lets say a div has 6 elements. When window size is small (mobile display) they would be in 3 rows of 2. And when window size gets big enough to allow 3 in a row to fit (maybe ipad display), then it would be 2 rows of 3. But when window size gets big enough to allow 4 in a row to fit (large monitor, etc), it would still keep 2 rows of 3 and instead the space between each element increases.

I found another question that pretty much covers what I'm asking: [Equal number of element per row with flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125444/equal-number-of-element-per-row-with-flexbox)
However the best answer is using jquery. Is there an easier way to do this with just styling or .jsx?

[Click here for the codepen link](https://codepen.io/Danya-Gordin/pen/ZEqgjKg) for my attempt below:

```html
<div class="container-main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">A</div>
    <div class="box">B</div>
    <div class="box">C</div>
    <div class="box">D</div>
    <div class="box">E</div>
    <div class="box">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container-main{
  
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
 
}
.container{

  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: red;
  align-content: space-evenly;
}

.box{
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
    background-color:#333;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:#fff;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
  }
```

As you can see in the figures below, when the `.container` width is 300px and 400px it is getting evenly distributed in the whole area of the div. But at 500px and 600px widths, it is no longer evenly distributed (2x3). How do I style it so that the elements always evenly fill up the entire div regardless of its width?

<kbd>[image]
Container width: 300px</kbd>

<kbd>[image]
Container width: 400px</kbd>

<kbd>[image]
Container width: 500px</kbd>

<kbd>[image]
Container width: 600px</kbd>

Comment: `display: grid` can help

Comment: I didn't understand your question completely. You can use `grid` and read about `auto-fill` and `minmax`

Comment: You will need Javascript to do what you want. There currently isn't a way using just CSS, has also been bugging me for ages